# MySQL does not unlock a locked table

Tags: mysql, locking, myisam

Sometimes our productive MySQL Server has many locked tables in the "show processlist". These locked tables get never unlocked, they were still locked after a few hours.

MySQL-Server 5.5, Debian Squeezy, MyISAM...
The table which were locked and never gets unlocked has ~200 Inserts per minute at peak and 2 Inserts per minute normaly.

Why does MySQL not unlock the table? In which situation it can happen?

Comment: Read lock? Write lock? You know this is a problem because you tried to write to the table and got a lock timeout?

Comment: I think Write locks. I use the "MySQL Workbench" -> "Server Status". The view shows only ~15 Connections with "State: Locked". There are SELECTs, INSERTs and UPDATEs, they are all locked and it's the same table.